# Running custom rake tasks on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I'm following the [Rake in Background](http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background) railscast to run some jobs in background. I'm able to do it on my localmachine.

But it doesn't work on heroku. How do I run these custom rake task on heroku?

I can run the tasks remotely from my terminal/shell using `heroku run rake my_task`. But the task is not running when I call it from controller as mentioned in the railscast.

I'm familier with delayed_job and other gems which do the same. But I want to implement my own rake task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error myself.

In the `call_rake` action the **`/usr/bin/rake`** path differ on different systems. Changed that to just **`rake`** and everything working normally on heroku.